# Variational Autoencoders VS Transformers

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoder, transformer

I'm relatively new to the field, but I'd like to know how do variational autoencoders fare compared to transformers?

Answer (score 6):

#### Variational AutoEncoder

---

**VAE** is an ***autoencoder*** whose encodings distribution is regularised during the training in order to ensure that its latent space has good properties allowing us to generate some new data. A **variational autoencoder (VAE)** provides a probabilistic manner for ***describing an observation in latent space***.

- [The Intuition Behind Variational Autoencoders](https://medium.com/@realityenginesai/understanding-variational-autoencoders-and-their-applications-81a4f99efc0d)
- [Variational autoencoders](https://www.jeremyjordan.me/variational-autoencoders/)

#### Transformers

---

**Transformers** are an ***architecture*** introduced in 2017, used primarily in the field of **NLP**, that aims to solve sequence-to-sequence tasks while handling long-range dependencies with ease. It ***relies entirely on self-attention to compute representations of its input and output WITHOUT using sequence-aligned RNNs or convolution***. The main tasks these Transformers are used for are classification, information extraction, question answering, summarization, translation, text generation, etc

The most popular Transformers are **BERT** and **GPT-2**. **Hugging Face** has other Transformers available for you to experiment with.

- [The Illustrated Transformer](http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/)
- [How do Transformers Work in NLP?](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/06/understanding-transformers-nlp-state-of-the-art-models/)

Comment: I'm more curious in which cases variational autoencoders could beat ChatGPT: Can you name some cases?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; transformers, in this context, are a method for optimizing the creation of an autoencoder. They aren't different things, so it doesn't make sense to compare them as if they are.